# Why is Hawkeye using a sword instead of bow and arrows?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, hawkeye, avengers-endgame

In the *Avengers: Endgame* trailer, Hawkeye is using a sword instead of bow and arrows. Why?

Comment: @I Love You 3000: Is there anything more I can add to my answer to improve it for you?

Comment: And I repeat that question. :)

Answer (score 17):

Based on the use of a sword, and his changed costume, there's a good chance that he's using the [Ronin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawkeye_(comics)#Return_and_New_Avengers) persona introduced in *[New Avengers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawkeye_(comics)#cite_note-72)*. There, he was borrowing the identity from [Echo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_(Marvel_Comics)) because he was assumed dead at the time, but here it may be a matter of him dodging the fact that he's supposed to be retired.

[image: Ronin on the cover of New Avengers]

This [has been confirmed](https://www.google.com/amp/amp.denofgeek.com/us/movies/marvel/278094/avengers-endgame-who-is-ronin), although the name did not wind up being used in the movie.

> After being nowhere to be found in Avengers: Infinity War, Hawkeye is front and center again in Avengers: Endgame. Unfortunately for Clint Barton, losing his family thanks to Thanos' snap drives him a little bonkers, and he spends a little time running around the MCU in a black costume, wiping out criminals with a samurai sword, under the moniker of Ronin (even though that name is never actually said in the movie).

Comment: This might end up being the case, and in my opinion is probably on the right track. But until the movie is released it's just speculation.

Comment: {nods} I guess I can accept that. It just seemed such a clear reference that it was worth mentioning.

Comment: You might also note that (in the comics) Hawkeye's original mentor was a guy named the Swordsman. While he's incredible with arrows, he's probably gotten some decent training with a sword as well. Admittedly, that bit of personal history isn't part of the MCU at this time, but it hasn't been explicitly invalidated either.

Comment: (Plus, the mask he's looking at looks similar to the Ronin mask.)